# El Capitan Realtek 8812au Installation stuck at "Destination Select"

Tags: network, wifi, macos

I'm trying to install driver for my D-Link DW-182 rev. C1 which uses RTL-8812AU Realtek chipset and supports Mac OS X via this ftp [link](http://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DWA-182/REVC/). ( ver. 2.3.1 )

[image: Destination Select]

What's the problem? Any help?
At least can I unpack it and install it manually?

Comment: This may or may not be something you already tried… Even though it's already highlighted, that particular installer type needs for you to actually click on the destination [even if there's only one possibility] before Continue will un-grey.

Comment: Having said that, it doesn't work for me either. It doesn't claim to support 10.11, though, only up to 10.10.

Comment: @Tetsujin then how to unpack it, it should have drivers and utilities inside, do you try to manually install it?

Comment: I had no desire to actually install it, just to test the install destination. You might find something like [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) could do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a ticket with D-Link Egypt and here's their reply:

[image: Dlink Egypt]
**Simply** it's working :)